# How dangerous to have disputed flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags, flag-history

Recently i received several of my flags back as `disputed`. Wanted to ask if it is dangerous to have `disputed` flags and if it's so, how many such flags might lead to a temporary ban of my privilege to flag posts?

Comment: [it is now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253117/revisions "see rev 2"): _Declined flags will "count against you", but disputed flags won't..._

Comment: My bro had three flags disputed and he ded.

Comment: @Will I'm sorry to hear that. Is he ok now?

Comment: @James ... he ded.

Comment: @Will Still? Well, I hope he recovers soon

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Disputed flags mean nothing. They reflect a dispute among peers; there is no effect, positive or negative, on your flagging history in so far as flagging privileges are concerned.

That said, if you find a large number of your flags are disputed you may wish to alter your flagging strategy in order to waste less of your own time as well as reduce the burden such flags place on others.

Comment: Disputed flags mean nothing... [yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243187/165773)? I for one "support the idea to introduce flagger accountability for disputed flags... flaggers who consistently and intensively fail, say, half of LQ reviews, would better be throttled and given a better chance to find out and learn about this..."

Comment: Shog at least for me the triage queue seams to be generating a lot of disputed flags because of picking SBI instead of unsalvageable.  Should I worry about those flags or not worry as of yet since triage might be changed?

Comment: Triage is still being worked on, but as a general rule you shouldn't be overly concerned by disputed flags anyway @nathan - they indicate disagreement, nothing more.