# Triage ban for voting to close crap

Tags: support, triage, review-suspension

I have over 3K helpful flags, according to my profile. Today, I'm banned from Triage due to 'too many declined flags.' Here is the topmost example of a question which I marked for closure in Triage and was 'declined':

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051108/ftp-folder-not-not-showing-all-image-files

[<10k image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGaEO.png)

Since when does Triage 'raise flags' that moderators need to process? I click 'unsalveagable' and I choose a vote-to-close reason. So, I'm just voting to close, am I not? And the whole point of requiring multiple votes on close is that it's a self-controlling process; so if for some reason my taste in close votes is not the same as everyone's, it's no big deal. So why is it ban-fodder?

Comment: I completely agree with your position here. This started to happen to me as well, and I completely abandoned the queue. Specifically [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219141/how-to-create-a-calculator-for-gamehostingjs) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218945/google-script-cut-and-paste-row) caused declined flags in a row in a short time span, I was warned in the dialog, and I just stopped out of frustration.

Comment: I have abandoned that queue as well for the exact same reason, even though I would like to think I had some tiny part in at least the motivation for its creation due to my incessant complaints via extremely well thought out proposals about low quality questions.

Comment: about time to declare something like it was in the past: [Close Votes review: I'm going on a strike!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208220/165773)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with triage. The timing may have been merely coincidental. For the above question, you flagged it as "very low quality" on the 5th via triage, and that flag was disputed by a triage review. That acts as if the flag wasn't cast at all, and doesn't harm you. I believe that you had a series of older flags declined at the same time for other reasons (close vote reviews, moderator declines, etc.), none of which involved triage. Those are what led to the ban.

Comment: @BradLarson I don't claim to have a perfect memory, but I'm fairly clear that I don't cast very many flags. I get (or got) 100 of flags because, apparently, I have a prior track record of casting them sensibly. What are you trying to tell me by banning me from the Triage queue (and nothing else) because a cluster of my flags cast over some period of time were disputed?

Comment: @Virus721 I wonder why all the linked questions are no longer there? OP has a point maybe?

Comment: I have experienced the same on the triage queue. The direct reason is, I guess, [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253497/1761793). I believe that the actual cause of this is the flawed design of the Triage q. It so happens that other reviewers might find a post slightly off-topic, and mark it 'Should be improved' while you mark it Unsalvageable. And thus you involve moderators who might feel so too (should be improved). Some mods may mark your flag helpful, while some might decline it. So I use either looks good or needs improvement. I use unsalvageable only in the most obvious cases.

Comment: @Virus721 Try a fact or two. I don't 'ask to close questions'. I vote to close questions. I have plenty of rep. We are _supposed_ to mark as 'unsalvageable' any question which the OP needs to fix -- needs improvement is only for things where we, ourselves, can fix it.

Comment: @bmargulies - To be clear, I didn't ban you from flagging, nor did I handle any of these flags. Beyond two "not an answer"-style flags that we declined, nothing in your recent history was handled by a moderator. That's what leads me to believe that the flag ban came instead from older close vote flags that were finally processed by reviewers. The ban is based on when flags are handled, not when they're cast, which [can lead to problems when close vote reviewers act on a bunch of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223970/135615). All I was saying is that I don't think triage is to blame.

Comment: @brad Larsen got it.

Comment: @BradLarson In light of that, shouldn't declined flags age away after a certain time/number of accepted flags? If I have a few declined flags from a year ago and then get one more in two years' time, even though I have a few hundred accepted flags inbetween, I would still get banned?

Comment: @TylerH - The timing is when flags are acted on, not when they are cast. If you had flags that were declined years ago, those would be well outside the calculation for the ban (which unfortunately lets a bunch of people keep casting dozens of "plz anser thz urgent" flags over the span of years). If you had cast flags that weren't acted on for a year, and that were suddenly declined, *that* would trigger a warning or temporary ban. Pretty much the only flags that last that long are close flags. In this case, about a month and a half's worth of "other" flags got burned down after the election.

Answer (score 89):

**Triage doesn't decline close flags.** [It *can* decline VLQ, Spam and Offensive flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday/300787#300787), but close flags can *at most* be disputed, **which do not contribute to flag bans.**

Furthermore, *you* can't get flag-banned for voting to close anything *anywhere*, because you far exceed the reputation requirements to *vote* to close, and thus can no longer raise close *flags*. Your votes either count toward the closure of a question, or... they don't. Full stop.

In the case of the particular question you linked to, you **voted** to close it as off-topic and **flagged** it as Very Low Quality...

- The **vote** counted toward the question being closed.
- The **flag** was *disputed*.

So others agreed with you that the question was off-topic, but disagreed that it was an abysmally bad question. And *even then*, this didn't contribute toward a flag ban, because - as I mentioned above - **Triage can't flag-ban you.** [Disputed flags don't count toward anything.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280606/how-dangerous-to-have-disputed-flags/280607#280607)

### So... Why *are* you flag-banned then?

Simple: 6 [qualifying flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) have been handled in the past 7 days, and 2 were declined. Note that these aren't actually flags you *raised* in the past 7 days - the mods are working through a backlog of "other" flags, and came across some flags you'd raised a month ago. The two relevant flags were "this should be a comment" on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389688/gibberish-characters-in-excel-export/29603679#29603679) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658238/rmi-server-application-doesnt-keep-on-running-silently-terminates/29662382#29662382).

Frankly, this is an unfortunate edge-case; as worthless as those flags were, banning you from flagging a month later doesn't accomplish much. I've adjusted the limits to avoid this (and thus implicitly lifted your ban).

Comment: Thanks. I will continue to flag less and less.

Comment: @bmargulies That or you could just flag things correctly...

Comment: As usual, flag if there's a serious problem that you simply can't handle on your own. "This answer is short" != "this answer should be a comment"; if you think the answer is lousy, downvote it - if it's *really* bad, VLQ-flag it (those get handled several orders of magnitude more quickly and have numerous automatic triggers that mostly just Do The Right Thing). If you're gonna choose "other", try to leave enough information that a skeptical moderator won't be led to assume you're trying to use them as proxy downvoters. Remember, moderators get the same number of votes per day as everyone else.

Comment: In these cases, I was applying a low bar for 'should be a comment' -- I was flagging anything of the form 'have you tried'? Whether I'm 'right' or 'wrong', clearly, this is too low a bar for the current mod consensus. So I should just downvote those cases. I can't convert things to comments myself, but these are 'clearly' not clearly cases that need that treatment.

Comment: @bmargulies for those "have you tried" I would attempt to edit so it becomes a strong imperative, instead of some kind of wimpy statement, failing that, NAA's/

Comment: I've [written about this before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263103/why-were-my-not-an-answer-flags-on-answers-that-consist-only-of-yes-declined/263128#263128), @bmargulies. Flagging based solely on a pattern-match is a waste of everyone's time. Presumably you *weren't* doing this, and had other reasons - but by excluding those reasons from the flag text you wasted the time you spent researching. Moderators are not *and should not be* a machine that blindly reacts to inputs - you elect them for their skill and judgment, and should expect them to use it.

Comment: I've been living a lie all along...

Comment: @Shog9 Perhaps a flag ban should notify me in some less indirect way than a line under the triage queue?

Comment: @bmargulies "Have you tried" is almost always followed by a potential solution - why do you think these should be comments? They do attempt to answer the question. There are hopelessly too many questions where you can't know 100% if a solution would work in some particular case, and even if it doesn't, the solution might work for other users visiting the question with seemingly the same problem, so an extended discussion in the comments to determine whether a solution works before answering seems worse than simply posting an answer.

Comment: Whatever.  I don't have time to figure out this system.  I might triage in the future, I might not. I might get banned and never know why. I might not care to investigate.